# Best way to perform mutually exclusive selection in a tableview in different sections in swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, multi-select, xcode8

I have a tableview with different sections, I need to be able to multiselect from different sections, but the rows in each section should be able to select mutually exclusive wise. For eg: in below screenshot I should be able to select either Margarita or BBQ Chicken from Pizza and same for Deep dish pizza but I should be able to multiselect between Pizza section and Deep dish pizza

[image]

Below is my code so far, I was wondering what would be the best way to approach this.

```
   let section = ["Pizza", "Deep dish pizza"]

    let items = [["Margarita", "BBQ Chicken"], ["Sausage", "meat lovers"]]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.section[section]
    }



    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return section.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return items[section].count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure a tableview is the appropriate choice here? A [picker](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/pickers/) sounds like a better choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create some data element to track the selection for each row.

I would suggest a dictionary of `[Int:Int]` where the key is the section and the value is the row.

When a row is selected, you can then easily check to see if another row is already selected in that section, and deselect it if required.

```
var rowSelections = [Int:Int]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let section = indexPath.section
        if let row = self.rowSelections[section] {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: IndexPath(row:row, section:section), animated: true)
        }
        self.rowSelections[section]=indexPath.row
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let section = indexPath.section
    self.rowSelections[section]=nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out, I created a method that would loop and check through all the rows and called it in both tableview didselect and deselect

```
func updateTableViewSelections(selectedIndex:IndexPath)
    {

        for  i in 0  ..< tableView.numberOfSections
        {
            for k in 0  ..< tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
            {

                if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: k, section: i))

                {

                    if sections.getType(index: i) == selectedIndex.section
                    {
                        if (selectedIndex.row == k && cell.isSelected)
                        {
                            cell.setSelected(cell.isSelected, animated: false)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Any solution that uses `cellForRow(at:)` won't work once the tableview has enough cells to scroll since `cellForRow(at:)` can only return rows that are on screen.  You can't rely on the tableview/cells representing state; you need to track state in a model somewhere so that you can use that when you return cells

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that.

Answer (score -1):

First allow multiple selection:

```
yourTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

To get the select rows:

```
let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

Then within the didselectrow function you can iterate through the selected rows and ensure that only 1 row within the section can be selected.